# deleting specific file type in directories using os.remove

Tags: python

I have around 600 movie folder in a directory
and every movie folder have an .srt and .txt file
example :

- movies_library/

  - movies_library/movie_1

    - movies_library/movie_1/movie1_name.pm4
    - movies_library/movie_1/movie1.srt
    - movies_library/movie_1/movie1.txt
  - movies_library/movie2

    - movies_library/movie_2/movie2_name.pm4
    - movies_library/movie_2/movie2.srt
    - movies_library/movie_2/movie2.txt

so I need to delete .srt and .txt , I wrote this code its work fine but I have two problems:

1. if you have a file.mp4 in the main movies library folder its make an error and stop the script.
2. the .DS store also stop the script.

```py
import os

SRT = input("enter file type: \n ")
src = input("Enter folder path: \n")

folders_in_src_path = os.listdir(src)

folders_path_list = []
for file in folders_in_src_path:
    full_folder_path = os.path.join(src, file)
    p = folders_path_list.append(full_folder_path)

folders_path_list.remove(src + '/.DS_Store')


for x in folders_path_list :
    file_in_folder = os.listdir(x)
    filtered_files=[file for file in file_in_folder if file.endswith(SRT) ]
    for file in filtered_files:
        path_to_filterd_files = os.path.join(x, file)
        os.remove(path_to_filterd_files)
```

Answer (score 0):

finding my solution in using pathlib and os

```
from pathlib import Path
import os

src_folder  = Path(input("insert path : \n"))
file_type = input("file type as mp4 :  \n" )

# use glob for directores and rglob for directories and subdirectories 
# [!.] to exclude hiddin files start with [ directory/.filename.filetype] cuz it generate an error while os.remove 

files_list = list(src_folder.rglob(f"[!.]*.{file_type}"))

# using X to add every filterd file path included in  list 
# to be removed item by item using os.remove
for X in files_list:
    os.remove(X)
```

updated thank to @tomerikoo

```py
from pathlib import Path

src_folder  = Path(input("insert path : \n"))
file_type = input("file type as mp4 :  \n" )

files_list = src_folder.rglob(f"[!.]*.{file_type}")

for X in files_list:
    X.unlink()
```

Comment: Why use `os` at all when using `pathlib`? Just use [`X.unlink()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.unlink)...

Comment: Also it is not necessary to convert the result of `rglob` to a list. Just iterate directly over it..

Comment: @Tomerikoo , thank you it work.

Comment: but how to see or access the glop generated list to see the file list ? <generator object Path.rglob at 0x7fa289d4ef90>

Comment: Ah sure. If you want to see it as a list, you will have to convert as it returns a generator. But if you're just going over it one by one in a loop, as you do above, there is no need to use a list at all...

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
import os

file_type = input("Enter file type: ")
folder_path = input("Enter folder path: ")

filelist = []

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(folder_path):
    for file in files:
        #append the file name to the list
        filelist.append(os.path.join(root,file))

#print all the file names
for name in filelist:
    delete_file = str(name)
    if delete_file.endswith(file_type):
        os.remove(delete_file)
        print("File deleted successfully.")
        break
else:
    print("No files found.")
```

Comment: thank you os.walk() is really helpful

Comment: Welcome! Please upvote if you liked it.